# How to avoid using-clause when template base types

Tags: c++, template-instantiation, template-inheritance

I am working on a library where the consumer writes a struct (Foo).
Foo uses special types (A,B) and attributes (Attribute) that are provided by the library.

The library will instantiate Foo with different templates.

To minimize clutter, we use masks, i.e. multitudes of templates are hidden into just one template that is a derived of MaskBase. This also allows us to specialize Attribute with cleaner code, given one of the individual derived of Mask (here MaskA and MaskB).

My question is:

- Can the boiler plate in line i and line ii be removed?

The question is relevant to us because we want the consumer code to be as simple as possible, for the convenience of the consumer.

A minor subquestion is whether the presented use of concepts is intended practice, or whether the concept of inheritance could be used in a more immediate way.

```cpp
#include<type_traits>
#include<concepts>
#include<iostream>


// base type declarations 
struct MaskBase{};

// concept definitions
template<typename Tmask> concept is_Mask = ( std::is_base_of_v<MaskBase,Tmask> );

// mask definitions
template<typename T> struct MaskA: MaskBase{};
template<typename T> struct MaskB: MaskBase{};


// Example Attribute implementation
template<typename Tmask> requires is_Mask<Tmask> struct Attribute; // declaration
template<typename T> struct Attribute<MaskA<T>>{}; // definition for MaskA
template<typename T> struct Attribute<MaskB<T>>{}; // definition for MaskB

// Foo base definitions
template<typename Tmask> requires is_Mask<Tmask> struct FooBase;

template<typename T>
struct FooBase< MaskA<T> >{
    using A = T;
    using B = int;
};

template<typename T>
struct FooBase< MaskB<T> >{
    using A = double;
    using B = std::pair<T,int>;
};

// Foo implementation
template<typename Tmask>
struct Foo: FooBase<Tmask>{
    //
    using A = typename Foo::A; // (Line i)
    using B = typename Foo::B; // (Line ii)
    //
    A x; // <-- the consumer would like to use types A and B like so in their implementation of Foo.
    B v;
    //
    Attribute<Tmask> a;
};

// ++++ utilization
int main(){
    Foo< MaskA<float > > fooA;
    Foo< MaskB<double> > fooB;
};
```

### Remark

I understand that the technical problem is related to the fact that `Foo` is not a complete type at the time when the consumer writes `A x`. Therefor, the line i is to signal to the compiler something like a forward declaration. Is this understanding accurate? If so, can this sort of declaration be moved into FooBase or somewhere where it does not need to be written by the consumer (and for each derived of FooBase that they implement)?

Comment: _"Can the boiler plate in line i and line ii be removed?"_ Yes, just write these out there?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ. So, removal just results in the error ``error: 'A' does not name a type``. Am I missing something?

Comment: `A x;
    B v;` => `Foo::A x;
    Foo::B v;` exactly why are you trying to avoid this??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you need [a bit more](https://godbolt.org/z/734TeWTM3) than that

Comment: @Caleth. You are right, the error is ``error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Foo<Tmask>'``. I added the remark as to clarify the issue and what I assume may help towards a solution.

Comment: @Caleth OK, I see. Though the question is why should the `using` statements be avoided?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: He wants to avoid the `using` statements, because `Foo` is a class that's being defined by the library consumer, and he doesn't want everybody who uses the library to have to write that boilerplate code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ. I understand that the matter of convenience is not just enough for you as a cause for a quest to avoid ``using``. I respect that. It is only convenience after all. Once you write your 40th derived of FooBase, you may agree it would be nice if it could be avoided still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to have some boilerplate here, or at the use of `A` and `B`, because `A` and `B` *might not be* types in some specialisations of `FooBase`.

Unfortunately, it doesn't matter that there aren't any such specialisations, nor would it matter if you constrained `Tmask` such that `FooBase<Tmask>::A` had to be a type.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. Can you help out with an example where these are not types? And then probably my assumption in my remark was wrong in that it is not only a forward declaration but also a specification that this is a type. Interesting.

Comment: And sorry if this goes beyond what is being asked, but the immediate follow-up question would be whether there is an alternative to the presented mask pattern that will remove said boilerplate. Since you are more knowledgeable, despite this being vague, would you offer to make a suggestion? This could be very helpful in simplifying our code.

Comment: @GRamon `template<> struct FooBase< MaskC >{ static double A = 0.0; std::string B = "stuff"; };` is such a specialisation.

Comment: @GRamon no, I don't think you can avoid it

Comment: Ah, I see, because the name has not been reserved at this point. Thanks. I suffered tunnel vision :)